# How to compare a date to a string

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I have a mysql query where I am trying to use a string in the where clause.

```
select s.schedule_date 
from schedule s 
WHERE DATE(s.schedule_date) = '2022-06-04'
```

and it does not work.
I have also tried
s.schedule_date = '2022-06-04'
DATE(s.schedule_date) = DATE('2022-06-04')

But nothing seems to work.  Most articles I have seen say the where in the SQL example should work.
[image]

[image]

```
select
    s.schedule_date,DATEDIFF(s.schedule_date,"2022-06-04")
from
    schedule s
WHERE
    s.schedule_date >= "2022-06-03" and
    s.schedule_date <= "2022-06-05";
```

Give me 1 when it should be 0.[image]

[image]

Comment: I can see the column datatype is `DATE`, so `s.schedule_date = '2022-06-04'` [should work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c3fdcb0fb9bcb266a1c4192a80f824c).

Comment: I tried <= and >= and it gives me dates greater or less than but not equal.  Any ideas?

Comment: I agree @FanoFN the documentation says it should work.

Comment: I just edited the question to show how it handles <= and >=

Comment: What mysql-version are you running?

Comment: mysqld  Ver 5.7.35 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL)).  Running from a docker image

Answer (score 3):

I turns out it was a DBeaver issue.  I changed the MySQL driver setting noDatetimeStringSync to true.  The default it false.  Not sure why it just started doing this

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the MySQL [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function: it converts a string to a date, given the input format, that in your case should be `%Y-%m-%d`.

```
SELECT s.schedule_date 
FROM schedule s 
WHERE DATE(s.schedule_date) = STR_TO_DATE('2022-06-04', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: can you share a fiddle? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gqzZAZqV4ds8QRzPi2bD5M/1 @Paul

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [CAST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp)-Function, to convert your strings into dates. Of course, CAST can also be used for any other transformation (INT to STRING, STRING TO CHAR(n), ...). In your case, the query should look like this:

```
    SELECT
    s.schedule_date, DATEDIFF(s.schedule_date, CAST("2022-06-04" AS DATE))
    FROM
    schedule s
    WHERE
    s.schedule_date >= CAST("2022-06-03" AS DATE) AND
    s.schedule_date <= CAST("2022-06-05" AS DATE);
```

Comment: I had to change the dates a little since I refreshed my database from production.  See image I just attached.  I tried running it on our production server and it works fine.  I deleted my local database and restored it from prod  and it still is doing the same thing.  I am thinking if is possibly a database setting?